# Image not taking parent height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have following `html`:

```
<div class='fullHeight'>
  <div class='flexbox'>
    <div class='first'>
      <p>foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class='second'>
      <p>bar</p>
      <img src='http://www.mandysam.com/img/random.jpg'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and `css`:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.fullHeight {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  maxHeight: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.first {
  background-color: magenta;
}
.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  widht: auto;
}
```

As long there is no image, everything works fine:

[image]

But as soon as a picture comes in, it overflows the container, instead of being shrinked to fit available height:

[image]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hanskre/pen/bGRVzWW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

in your `.second` class, that's why the `flex` property isn't doing anything. Also it should be `max-height` instead of `maxHeight` and `width` instead of `widht`.

You can use `background-image` for your purpose.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.fullHeight {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.first {
  background-color: magenta;
}
.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
.container {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: url('http://www.mandysam.com/img/random.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='fullHeight'>
  <div class='flexbox'>
    <div class='first'>
      <p>foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class='second'>
      <p>bar</p>
      <div class="container">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for making me aware of my mistakes & typos. But unfortunately, your solution is not fixing the problem. I updated the codepen https://codepen.io/hanskre/pen/bGRVzWW

Comment: @Hans what exactly do you want to do? Change the aspect ratio of the image so that it fit in the parent or showing the whole image without distorting it?

Comment: I want to show the whole image without distorting it but not overflowing respecting the 100vh parent (i.e. stetch only to the available height).

Comment: @Hans edited, use background-image instead for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add height and width properties to your image. Or just height. Maybe also `object-fit: cover;`

```
.second img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: If I do this, it's occupying parent's full height but not respecting that there are other children of parent.

Answer (score 0):

Using positions is the other solution but it's very risky and it depends on your plan for future code in this project!!

```
.second {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  widht: auto;
  position:relative
}
.second img{
  height: 95%;
  width: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```